# How do I set the consistency level for a counter column family in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, hector

I have a keyspace already defined. Can I set the consistency level for a counter column family (read and write) to ALL without affecting the rest of the keyspace? I cannot figure out how to do it from the help in the cli, but I suppose it should be possible. Something along the lines of:

```
update column family COUNTERS with ________
```

I am using the Java Hector API.

Comment: are you using CQL? Or do you want to know only for the CLI?

Comment: @LyubenTodorov I updated the question. I am using java hector API. I want all operations on a counter column family to be atomic (consistency: ALL). Any ideas on how to achieve this with the hector API?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about CQL3 but you can do this while reading/writing. Example thrift client:

```
client.add('key1', ColumnParent(column_family='Counter1'), CounterColumn('c1', 100), ConsistencyLevel.ONE)
client.add('key1', ColumnParent(column_family='Counter1'), CounterColumn('c1', -50), ConsistencyLevel.ONE)
```

Comment: I updated the question. I am using java hector API. I want all operations on a counter column family to be atomic (consistency: ALL). Any ideas on how to achieve this with the hector API? I saw the thrift client example in cassandra's docs, but there is no help available for Hector to do the same. It is a column family with counter columns.